# Sum multiple columns according to NaN status of other columns

Tags: pandas, nan

I'm trying to get the sum of four columns based on the NaN status of four other columns

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 A    B    C    D    A_pct  B_pct  C_pct  D_pct
100  NaN  NaN  100   5%      95%     0%     0%
100  NaN  250  100   1%      84%     15%    0%
```

I want to sum A_pct >> D_pct where the condition that A-D <> NaN is being met.

Hence, for the first row, the result would be 5%; for the second row, the result would be 16%

What I've done is as follows:

```
Pct_Sum = (df.loc[(df["A"].notna()) & (df["B"].notna()) & (df["C"].notna()) & df["D"].notna()),
 df[["A_pct","B_pct","C_pct","D_pct"]]].sum(axis=1))
```

However, this returns the ValueError: "Cannot index with multidimensional key"

Please can you steer me in the right direction to correct this?

Thank you!

Comment: If interested, I used np.where to help me with this. ie Pct_sum = (np.where(df.A.notna(),df.A_pct, 0) + np.where(df.B.notna(),df.B_pct, 0) + np.where(df.C.notna(),df.C_pct, 0) + np.where(df.D.notna(),df.D_pct, 0))

Comment: why the second row's result would be 16% rather than 38.5%?

Comment: In the second row, cols A, C & D <> NaN; A_pct + C_pct + D+pct = 16%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: sum(x[:4].notnull().values * (x[4:].str[:-1].astype(float)/100).values), axis=1)
```